# create a border around the the question and answer

Tags: html, css

The code works fine. What it does is it hides something, in this case the answer. Once the question has been clicked, it shows the answer. Anyhow - what I have been trying to do it once something it clicked, I would like the question and the answer to be different - like have a different background color, or a red border around the questions and answer - something to delineate it from the rest of the questions. Once I click on something else, it would disappear. I have been trying to do that in css, and can't do it.

```
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <title> THis is the title </title> 
 <style> 
 .clicker {
 border-style: solid; 
 border-width: 1px; 
 display: inline-block; 
 padding: 5px ; 
 outline:none;
 cursor:pointer;
 }

 .hiddendiv{
 display:none;
 padding: 5px; 
 }
 .clicker:focus + .hiddendiv{
 dispay:block;
 }
 </style> 
  </head>
  <body>

  <h2> Flashcards</h2>
  <div class="clicker" tabindex="1">
  <p>This is the first question </p>
   </div>
   <div class="hiddendiv">
   <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/champions-1/512/Champions-04-512.png"/> 
   </div>
   <p> </p>
   <div class="clicker" tabindex="1">       <p>Second question </p>
   </div>
   <div class="hiddendiv"> 
 <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/champions-1/512/Champions-04-512.png"/> 
 </div>
 <p> </p> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: what is the `dispay`

Comment: @DogukanCavus Yeah, I saw that, too (fixed).

Comment: Off-topic, but if you're worried about `tabindex`, just use a native `<button>`. You get `tabindex`/enter key/spacebar for free in every browser, ever.

Answer (score 1):

Solved your problem. Please run below code.
I hope you are looking for this feature only.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> THis is the title </title>
  <style>
    .clicker {
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5px;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .hiddendiv {
      display: none;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .clicker:focus+.hiddendiv {
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    .clicker:focus {
      background: green;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2> Flashcards</h2>
  <div class="clicker" tabindex="1">
    <p>This is the first question </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hiddendiv">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/champions-1/512/Champions-04-512.png" />
  </div>
  <p> </p>
  <div class="clicker" tabindex="1">
    <p>Second question </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hiddendiv">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/champions-1/512/Champions-04-512.png" />
  </div>
  <p> </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```css
.clicker {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 5px;
   outline: none;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 .hiddendiv {
   display: none;
   padding: 5px;
 }
 
 /* Highlight focused question */
 .clicker:focus {
   background-color: green;
   border: 2px solid darkgray;
   color: white;
 }

 /* Highlight focused answer */
 .clicker:focus+.hiddendiv {
   display: block;
   background-color: darkgray;
   border: 2px solid green;
 }
```

```html
<h2> Flashcards</h2>
<div class="clicker" tabindex="1">
  <p>This is the first question </p>
</div>
<div class="hiddendiv">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/champions-1/512/Champions-04-512.png" />
</div>
<p> </p>
<div class="clicker" tabindex="1">
  <p>Second question </p>
</div>
<div class="hiddendiv">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/champions-1/512/Champions-04-512.png" />
</div>
<p> </p>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akLto14v/2/)